# All pages after level 1 showing 404 after WordPress migration plugin - how to fix?

Tags: 404-error, rewrite-rules, migration

I am in the process of moving my blog away from GoDaddy (yey!) to HostGator.  I used the migration plugin on GoDaddy tat created the gz archive of the database, and I copied all my files over to the new host.

My front page displays fine, but it is everything after this that shows 404 - ie. ~/profile-who-am-i/, and other category pages.

I suspect some rewriting rule isn't being followed after installing everything on HostGator and would like some assistance on how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalink Settings.
However it's set, change it to something else, one of the other formats. I had an issue moving, same symptom as you described, and this fixed it.

You can also see [this help guide](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6313/fixing-permalink-issues-with-wordpress) on Go Daddy for help with this issue. (this edit added by another user. NP, but details almost identical. /JTP)

Comment: You actually don't need to change anything, just save it the way it is and everything should be fine.

Comment: @sim_92 - You mean just save the setting as-is will set things straight? If so, that's great.

Comment: Ha! Glad to help.